# Tableau - display last three dates in column

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have the following objects in Tableau dashboard: change_id and entry_date

Change_id is unique but entry_date can appear multiple times due to date of change modification.

As an example:

CH123   1/1/2022
1/3/2023
1/4/2023
1/5/2024

How do I create a field to display only last two dates?

I was trying the following: RANK(MAX({FIXED [Change ID]:max([Entry Date])})) and then filtering out only 1 and 2 values. It is working fine unless there are multiple change requests and Tableau starts to assign continuous numbers to all change requests.

Comment: What are the columns in your source data? Do you have one data row per change_id? or one data row per change_id/entry_date pair? i.e. what is the "level of detail" or "granularity" of your input data?

Comment: Are your date fields only dates? or do they include times also -- i.e. a datetime in Tableau speak? If they are only times, how do you sequence records that have the same date? is the change id guaranteed to be increasing only? Show some sample input data

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can use this snippet ([source](https://www.simboli.eu/p.php?URL_short=TABLEAU_CALC_SECOND_MAX_DATE_OVERALL)):

```
// Second max date overall
{ FIXED : MAX(
    IF [US Release Date]={ FIXED : MAX([US Release Date])}
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE [US Release Date] END
)}
```

adding `change_id` to the dimensions to include into the context (so after the `FIXED` words).